# Correct way to unit test CrudRepository.save()

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, crud-repository

I have a service class which queries the `CRUDRepository` based on `id, name and money`.

If data exists, it will extract the money, add 100 to it and save the updated object in the repository.
If data does not exist, it will create a new object and save it in the repository.

`Person.java`

```
@Value
@Builder
public class Person {

    private final UUID id;
    private final String name;
    @With
    private final BigDecimal money;
    
}
```

`Service.Java`

```
private Person updateOrSave(final UUID id, final String name) {

        final Optional<Person> existingPerson = myRepo.findByIdAndName(id, name);

        if (existingPerson.isPresent()) {
             updatedPerson = existingPerson.withMoney(existingPerson.getMoney().add(new BigDecimal(100)));
            return myRepo.save(updatedPerson);
        } else {
            return myRepo.save(Person.builder()
                .id(id)
                .name(name)
                .money(money)
                .build()));
        }
    }
```

I need to write a unit test for this scenario where data exists.
I am able to write the testcase but the issue is `myCrudRepository.save()` returns `null`.

So this is how I am testing it.

`Test.java`

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class PersonTest {

    @Mock
    private MyRepo myRepo;

    @InjectMocks
    private Service service;
    
    
    
    @Test
    void updateExistingMoney() {

        final UUID id = UUID.randomUUID();
        final String name = "TestName";


        final Optional<Person> person = Optional.of(Person.builder()
                .id(id)
                .name(name)
                .money(new BigDecimal(10))
                .build());

        final Person finalPerson = Person.builder()
                .id(id)
                .name(name)
                .money(new BigDecimal(110))
                .build()

        when(myRepo.findByIdAndName(id, name))
            .thenReturn(person);

        service.updateOrSave(id, name);

        verify(myRepo).save(finalPerson);

    }
    

Is this correct way of testing or is it wrong ?
```

Comment: So what's not working?  Please read [ask]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the concept of Argument captors to capture the object, which was passed as an argument to the mocked repo.

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class PersonTest {

    @Mock
    private MyRepo myRepo;

    @InjectMocks
    private Service service;

    @Captor
    private ArgumentCaptor<Person> personCaptor;


    @Test
    void updateExistingMoney() {

        final UUID id = UUID.randomUUID();
        final String name = "TestName";


        final Optional<Person> person = Optional.of(Person.builder()
                .id(id)
                .name(name)
                .money(new BigDecimal(10))
                .build());

        final Person finalPerson = Person.builder()
                .id(id)
                .name(name)
                .money(new BigDecimal(110))
                .build()

        when(myRepo.findByIdAndName(id, name))
                .thenReturn(person);

        service.updateOrSave(id, name);

        verify(myRepo).save(personCaptor.capture());

        final Person actual = personCaptor.getValue();

        // Do checks on expected person vs. the actual one
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this. So my testcase was working fine. I just did not know how can I capture the result and assert on the values. Appreciate all the help.